# Building mono 2.8 under Windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mono, compiler-errors

While trying to compile the mono 2.8 sources under VS2010
i am getting following errors:

build only mono project:

> error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libmono.lib' \msvc\LINK mono
>
> IntelliSense: cannot open source file "glib.h" \metadata\lock-tracer.h

build complete mono solution:

> \mono\profiler\mono-profiler-logging.c(9): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config.h': No such file or directory
>
> \mono\profiler\mono-cov.c(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mono/metadata/profiler.h': No such file or directory
>
> \mono\utils\monobitset.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'glib.h': No such file or directory

Comment: what source? from git? from tarball? mono-2.8-gtksharp-2.12.10-win32-9.exe?

Comment: does glib.h and libmono.lib really not exists?

Comment: Maybe it's me, but mono is a unix implementation of .NET. Why don't you install the .NET framework on Windows?

Comment: @Peter van Kekem: The more interesting question is, why is he compiling it from source anyway, and why isn't he using MonoDevelop for it? (TO answer your question, maybe he needs Mono to test applications against it.)

Comment: @Bobby: MD almost doesn't work under Windows. afaik it's an official politics of MD team because spending resources to make it work makes no sense because VS, even Express, is better anyway. So they targets MD for *nix

Comment: @Peter: Installing Mono on Windows makes sense if an application is written for Mono from the beginning, is Forms and targeted to GTK#. So to test it to be sure it works properly on Windows you need to install Mono+GTK# on Windows

Comment: @abatishchev: What? It's working fine and very good on my XP...but that's OT, I fear.

Comment: @Bobby: Glad to hear that. Thing are changing. But for many years it was actual situation what I described

Comment: @abatishchev sources are from http://mono-project.com/OldReleases version 2.8, GTK# for .net 2.12.10. The glib.h exists and i checked include directory settings in VS. I am searching my mono trees for the libmono.lib atm.

Comment: @Peter van Kekem The mono-develop ide seems kinda bugged under windows. the mono sources are written in c so why should i use mono-develop? i followed instructions from http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_VSNET

Comment: @Gobliins: As far as I could remember, when I tried to compile Mono under Windows using VS I ran some issues with dependencies package and environment variable leading to it

Comment: ok i found out that the libmono.lib is missing. I will research this issue

Comment: @Peter van Kekem, Mono is cross platform. PS3, Wii and iOS aren't running Unix.

Comment: Those instructions https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/README.vsnet are very old, and relied on VS2005. I'm not sure everything was rightfully updated to work with VS2010. Anyway libmono.lib should be compiled from the very solution (it is a project which mono depends), but beware of hardcoded paths, as warned in that readme.

Comment: ok i give the mono-develop 2.2 a chance for the solution file, but mono-develop doesnt seem to know the .vsproj types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the msvc build is broken.  This happens frequently as no one on the Mono team tests their changes with Microsoft's compiler.

The msvc build is mainly maintained by an awesome contributor, but he only fixes it he gets the time.

Comment: Could be, i tried to build the same version under linux which gives me also some errors. But trying a different version it worked without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a linux box? Try [this way](http://www.mono-project.com/Cross-compiling_Mono_for_Windows)

Comment: Why not just use MINGW then? Much easier.